# validation to check database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, validation, server-side

I am using jquery to do client side validation of a form. This is how I do it:

```
 $("#registerForm").validate({

            rules: {

                BCNumber : { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10 },
                Username : { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10 },
                Password : { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10 },
                SecurityQuestion : { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10 },
                SecurityAnswer : { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 10 },

            }
```

but for one of them I need to check database and if it exist submit the form, I was thinking once the submit button is clicked I can check and pass my true or false value to jquery.

Is this possible to do with jquery, if so can someone please show me?

Comment: You can make a server-side script to query the database, and query the script with AJAX?

Comment: @11684 can u provide a sample pls

Comment: I don't know asp.net, but to search 'query database asp.net' won't be hard for google. For the AJAX part you've got examples enough below, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX

```
$("#registerForm").submit(function(){
 var  id=//find the value to be checked
   $.get("url?id="+id,function(data){
       if(data=="valid"){
          //submit the form
          }else
             {
            return false;
             }
      })
})
```

First of all find the value to be checked with database and send it using AJAX `xmlhttpRequest`.if it is valid than `echo valid` else return `false`;

Comment: thanks for that.how do i send it using ajax xmlhttpRequest? can you pls give a full example if you can

Comment: why do you need `xmlhttprequest` ? you can do this work using jquery-ajax very simply and with security also

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4fLM/9/

I hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with asp.net. You can use whole jQuery ajax if you like else you might like to see how ajax works in asp.net this might help you http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_callback.asp . Beside the main idea here is to disable default form submit so that we can check backend for validation using ajax when we try to submit form. And if backend validates the data then we can submit data from javascript, else we just show error message. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validate supports a rule type called [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) which does what you want.  It looks like this:

```
$("#registerForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Username : { 
              required: true, 
              minlength: 5, 
              maxlength: 10,
              remote: 'check_username.php'
            }
        }
});
```

Then you create the `check_username.php` script and have it return a JSON `true` value if the username is valid, or a `false` value or error message if it is invalid.